# Python OpenCV--Email Doesn't Sent Images Saved from OpenCV

Tags: python-3.x, email, opencv

I have basically 2 functions. One is capturing the face detected at my laptop and i want to receive an email with the face of the user who is sitting on my chair. My issue is that the code is taking the pictures, but is not running the email submission. Can someone please help?

```
from imutils.video import VideoStream
import imutils, time, cv2, sys
import smtplib, os
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.image import MIMEImage
from email.message import Message
from email.mime.audio import MIMEAudio
from email import encoders

def take_picture():
    detector = cv2.CascadeClassifier("haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml")
    vs = VideoStream(src=0).start()
    time.sleep(2.0)
    total = 0
    while True:
        frame = vs.read()
        orig = frame.copy()
        frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=600)
        rects = detector.detectMultiScale(
            cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY), scaleFactor=1.1, 
            minNeighbors=5, minSize=(30, 30))
        for (x, y, w, h) in rects:
            cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
            if rects is not None and total <5:
                p="/Users/Desktop/atentie/mail/"+str(total)+".png"
                cv2.imwrite(p, orig)
                total+=1        
            else:
                break
    print("Initiez procedura de update root!")          
def send_email():
    files = "/Users/Desktop/atentie/mail/"
    filenames = [os.path.join(files, f) for f in os.listdir(files)] 
    fromaddr = “mail”
    toaddr = “mail”
    Cc=“mail”
    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['From'] = fromaddr
    msg['To'] = toaddr
    msg['Cc']=Cc
    msg['Subject'] = "Atentionare Cineva Va Foloseste Laptopul"

    body = "Cineva se joaca la laptopul tau"
    msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain')) 
    for file in filenames:
      part = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
      part.set_payload(open(file, 'rb').read())
      encoders.encode_base64(part)
      part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="%s"' % file)
      msg.attach(part)
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    server.starttls()
    server.login(fromaddr, “pass”)
    text = msg.as_string()
    server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddr, text)
    server.quit()
    print("Initiez procedura de trimitere email catre root!")
take_picture()
# time.sleep(2)
send_email()
# raise SystemExit
```

Comment: You have placed `send_email()` separately. Placing it within `take_picture()` will perhaps make it work. Right now you are just looping in `send_email()`

Comment: is the same thing! there are 2 functions and they are called separately, the issue is that is not working to send the email. it is working only if i make 2 files and then to call the send function from a different file is working;but both in the same file doesn't run. do you know why?

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the following logic:

```
def send_picture(p): 
    # *** SEND_PICTURE_LOGIC ***
    # Take the input picture p passed as argument 
    # Send this picture to email 

def take_picture():
    # *** TAKE_PICTURE_LOGIC ***
    # If somebody is sitting on my chair
    # take a picture and call it currentPicture
    # Call send_picture function with the currentPicture acquired
    send_picture(currentPicture)
```

This will result in sending an email for each acquisition

This should solve your problem

Comment: Exactly! This is what I mentioned in my comment!